# Return to cordova app after Keycloak authentication

Tags: cordova, authentication, keycloak

I have a Keycloak cordova-native app that once launched, correctly displays keycloak's username/password form, but after successfully authenticating, displays ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to redirect to the app. The redirectURI is currently set to 'http://localhost'.

I used this example https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/cordova-native

Here's the keycloak initiation...

```
var keycloak = new Keycloak();
    
keycloak.init({
     adapter: 'cordova-native'
     responseMode: 'query',
     onLoad: 'login-required',
     redirectUri: 'http://localhost'
 }).success(updateState).error(error);
```

So my question is, what redirectUri should I set it to redirect back to the app?

Answer (score 0):

I found out this below link. Please check if this will help you.
https://keycloak-docs.github.io/deploy-docs/dev/master/securing_apps/index.html#hybrid-apps-with-cordova

Here it is mentioned :-
*The default is cordova, which the adapter will automatically select if no adapter type has been configured and window.cordova is present. When logging in, it will open an InApp Browser that lets the user interact with Keycloak and afterwards returns to the app by redirecting to http://localhost. Because of this, you must whitelist this URL as a valid redirect-uri in the client configuration section of the Administration Console.*

Answer (score 0):

In [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/cordova-native/www/index.html#L62) `redirectUri` is `android-app://org.keycloak.examples.cordova/https/keycloak-cordova-example.github.io/login`. [Config file](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/cordova-native/config.xml#L16) from example have this element `<universal-links>` which is connected to [cordova-plugin-deeplinks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-deeplinks) and have same value as mentioned earlier `redirectUri`. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-deeplinks#modify-web-pages) describes how to create a link between your mobile content and the page on the website.